# Vim - Random "syntax=" text appearing in editor

Tags: vim, syntastic

Here's what I'm talking about.

[image: Figure 1]

On line 2 there is this highlighted block of "syntax=" text. It doesn't belong there and and will appear (seemingly) randomly. If I sweep over it in visual mode it goes away. I suspect that it's something to do with syntastic but I could easily be wrong since I'm only an intermediate when it comes to vim.

Here are the plugins I'm using,

```
YouCompleteMe
emmet-vim
html5.vim
nerdcommenter
python-mode
syntastic
tmp
vim-airline
vim-colors-solarized
vim-gitgutter
vim-javascript-syntax
vim-jinja
vim-js-indent
```

and here's my vimrc

```
execute pathogen#infect()
execute pathogen#helptags()

syntax on

" set [normal],rc open up the vimrc in a new buffer
let mapleader = ","
nmap <leader>rc :tabedit $MYVIMRC <CR>

" Stock Configurations
set laststatus=2
set nu
set t_Co=256
set autoread
set background=dark
set shiftwidth=4
set tabstop=4
set autoindent
set noswapfile
set nocompatible
set nowrap
set syntax

colorscheme solarized

" Autoclose YouCompleteMe Documentation Preivew after inserting
let g:ycm_autoclose_preview_window_after_insertion = 1

" Set the powerline fonts
let g:airline_powerline_fonts = 1
```

Also! Feel free to critique and make suggestions about my plugins and vimrc. I haven't spent a lot of time tuning things so any input would be rad!

Comment: If you think it is about syntastic, try to deactivate it. put a line likes this let `g:pathogen_disabled = ['syntastic']` before your `pathogen#infect` line, and try it again

Comment: You're describing a redraw bug.  Syntastic doesn't have access to low-level redraws, although it's known to _trigger_ bugs like this occasionally, thanks to the way Vim works.  Consider reporting the problem to `vim_dev`.

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo I had no luck with disabling Syntastic. However, I was able to isolate the problematic plugin which is vim-gitgutter.